# Expirar tempo de uso do usuario Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Estou fazendo um sistema de *login* em C# em que o usuário ao fazer login vai ser verificado seu login, senha e o tempo que lhe resta para usar o sistema. 
Até a parte de verificar login e senha eu consegui fazer, mas estou com problema ao verificar o tempo de uso. Por exemplo, ele não pode usar quando chegar determinada data.

Segue meu código até aqui:

```
try
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = @login AND userPass  = @senha ";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=; user=; password=; database=; Port=3306;");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", this.usuario.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", this.senha.Text);

    con.Open();

    int a = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (a > 0)// caso login e senha e tempo de uso OK
    {
        Form1 segundo = new Form1();
        this.Hide();
        segundo.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Seu tempo de uso acabou");
    }

}
catch 
{
    MessageBox.Show("User or Pass Incorrect!");
    usuario.Text = "";
    senha.Text = "";
}
```

No meu banco eu tenho os seguintes campos: userID, userName, userPass, DateExpiration

Simulando uma situação, o usuário foi cadastrado hoje e só pode fazer login até o dia 25/02/2017. Eu quero que dia 26/02/2017 ele não consiga mais fazer login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mantendo a lógica da sua implementação, você pode declarar sua instrução SQL assim:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userName = @login AND userPass  = @senha AND DateExpiration >= DATE(@dataAtual)";
```

E "assinar" os parâmetros assim:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", this.usuario.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", this.senha.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataAtual", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: Obriga funcionou exatamente como eu queria